# Bulk SQL Update changing certain phrases throughout an entire database to a new phrase

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update every single match in an entire database (all tables) so that they are all updated to the new one, there is about 4,000 matches by using search but I can't seem to figure out a correct way to update

- `phrase here` to `new text`
- `Phrase Here` to `New Text`
- `phrase-here` to `new-text`
- `Phrase-Here` to `New-Text`

**Needs to be case specific**!

I know I need to start with `Update *` but I can't see how using replace() would work, because I need to tell it what table to field I need to change.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you wanted to achieve it and whether it was a one-off solution or something you'd need to recreate and do over and over - you could do a solution where you input each table name into the query and execute, or if you have lots and lots of tables, create a list of tables, and then loop through those tables.  So, this is assuming we have something like this:
Updating
oldtable1 --> newtable1
oldtable2 --> newtable2 and so on

::Each table one at a time::
Use a subquery to cycle through the columns in an old table to bring them into a new table.

```
USE <YOURDATABASE>;

UPDATE dbo.newTable1
SET col1=col2
WHERE somecolumn IN (SELECT somecolumn FROM YOURDATABASE.dbo.oldTable1
```

To loop through the list of tables, you could create a list of the tables using

```
CREATE TABLE myTables
    AS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES)
```

and depending on how you have your tables named, you could get just a list of your old ones to cycle through using

```
CREATE TABLE myTables
    AS (SELECT TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'old%');
```

Then you'd cycle through the tables and their respective new ones with your update statement.
Additionally, you could get into using a MERGE statement, which may take a bit more effort, but I think it'd end up with a cleaner result.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much on the subject, but I might be able to point you in a direction at least.

If you build the SQL command into a string first, then execute it with EXEC(), that should allow you to use variables for your field and table names.

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @sqlCmd varchar(1000)
DECLARE @Table varchar(100)
DECLARE @Field varchar(100)
DECLARE @OriginalValue varchar(100)
DECLARE @ResultValue varchar(100)

SET @Table = 'TestTable'
SET @Field = 'TestField'
SET @OriginalValue = 'This is a test message.'
SET @ResultValue = REPLACE(@OriginalValue,'is','i-s')
SET @sqlCmd = 'UPDATE '+@Table+' SET '+@Field+' = '''+@ResultValue+''' WHERE '+@Field+' = '''+@OriginalValue+''''
EXEC (@sqlCmd)
```

Obviously yours will be more complicated, looping through search results and dynamically populating the variables, but I hope this gives you somewhere to start. At least until someone comes up with a more complete answer. :)

Some related reading: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html